# How to add "clear" as an option to the ranges menu?

Tags: jquery, daterangepicker

I'm using the jQuery daterangepicker plugin (http://www.daterangepicker.com/) and I would like to know if anyone has added, or can figure out how to add, a "Clear" option to the ranges menu that, when selected, clears the input value?

**Using a basic text input:**

```
<input type="text" name="txtDateRange" id="txtDateRange" value="" />
```

**With this instantiation code:**

```
    $('#txtDateRange').daterangepicker({
        startDate:  moment().subtract(29, 'days'),
        endDate: moment(),
        ranges: {
           'Today': [moment(), moment()],
           'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
           'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
           'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
           'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
           'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')],
           'Clear' : []
        }
    });
```

**Produces this result:**

[image]

How can I bind to whatever event the plugin is using when a menu option is selected so I can simply set the text input value to an empty string when the "Clear" menu item is selected?

**== UPDATE ==**

Be sure to use the updated solution in the selected answer.  Works perfectly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>You can use the callback (second optional param) function to clear the input if `start` and `end` are invalid dates and pass two values that are not valid for moment.js in the array:</strike>

```js
$('#txtDateRange').daterangepicker({
  startDate: moment().subtract(29, 'days'),
  endDate: moment(),
  ranges: {
    'Today': [moment(), moment()],
    'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
    'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
    'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
    'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
    'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')],
    'Clear': ['', '']
  }
}, function (start, end) {
  if (!start._isValid && !end._isValid) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      $('#txtDateRange').val('').trigger('change');
    })
  }
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />

<input type="text" name="txtDateRange" id="txtDateRange" value="" />
```

You can use any two invalid values as dates: `[null,null]`, but not `[undefined,undefined]`, as an `undefined` moment defaults to `moment()`, which is `now`, therefore `._isValid`.

You can see the callback being used on their [examples page](http://www.daterangepicker.com/#examples).

---

Update. Better UX and overall performance (methinks):

```js
$('#txtDateRange').daterangepicker({
  startDate: moment().subtract(29, 'days'),
  endDate: moment(),
  ranges: {
    'Today': [moment(), moment()],
    'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
    'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
    'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
    'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
    'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')],
    'Clear': [,]
  }
}, function (start, end, label) {
  if (label === 'Clear')
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setEndDate(this.endDate[
        this.endDate.valueOf() - this.startDate.valueOf() > 1440 ? 'subtract' : 'add'
      ](1,'days'));
      $(this.element).val('');
    })  
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />

<input type="text" name="txtDateRange" id="txtDateRange" value="" />
```

Comment: Leaving the "Clear" menu item as active causes the "Custom Range" menu feature to fail when selected after clicking Clear. I added the code shown in my updated question to get around this issue.

Comment: I see what you mean. I can't spend time on this until later tonight. You'll need to catch the constructor event of the calendar and pass a valid `moment()` instead of any invalid `start` or `end`. If that's difficult (or there's no method for catching it - which I doubt), you probably want to completely destroy the instance and create a new one on next interaction. Btw, your initial request doesn't make much sense, as when you init the component it's not "empty". It's today-today. Why would you want to empty it? It's better practice to mark whether or not it's pristine.

Comment: All good points. The input is initially empty, it is cleared right after instantiation.  The start/end date settings just give the plugin something to use internally so that if a user goes into the range menu and selects "Custom Range" the start/end values are what are used.  Since the input is initially empty the user will have had to have interacted with the plugin to set it to any value and will then know that is where they can also go to "clear" the input again if desired.  I have also updated my question with a simpler solution to the custom range issue after clear.

Comment: I updated with a practical solution (what I'd do). Note it's only visual clearing. Rather than passing invalid values to `moment` it's a lot less intrusive to simply check the label and hide the text of the input, while leaving defaults into place. The value is exactly the same as `Today` after clearing it. If you need to know the difference between them, set something in the callback.

Comment: Nevermind CSS. The solution is simpler: if `label` is `Clear`, set `val()` to empty string. No errors whatsoever, everything good. Happy coding!

Comment: Still has problems. Apparently the callback is not always run. If `Today` and `Clear` have same values, the callback is not run when switching between them. Even if you do make them different, the callback is still not run when you: select Clear, open it again and select Clear again. Because no change has been recorded. I might have a fix...

Comment: Finally fixed. Bugger!